# Putting XML file in Remote Server Folder without using WebService

Tags: android, xml, sockets, ftp

I am building an app that generates xml file from database. I want to put that xml file in a specific folder of Remote Server. I don't want to use webservice. Is there any way i can connect my Android App directly to Remote Server and paste a file in it.

**Edit**

Using FTP via Sockets will work?